# Giving a range for random.sample with strings/elements of a list

Tags: string, python-3.x, random, range, sample

I would like to create a variable which contains a name with 3-7 random letters. (It doesn't matter if the name is incorrect). I know how to do it to contain 3 letters but I just don't have a clue how to handle a range with letters (string/list). This is my code so far:

```
import random
ABC = ['A', 'Á', 'B', 'C'... just imagine every single letter of the Hungarian alphabet as a list]
name = random.sample(ABC, 3)
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
name = random.sample(ABC, 3) or random.sample(ABC, 4)
```

but it didn't work, of course. Can you guys help me out, please? :)

Comment: Add the language tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.sample(ABC, 3)` returns a list. As follows

```
>>> random.sample(ABC, 3)
['q', 'h', 'x']
```

you can convert it to string using `join` method

```
>>> a = random.sample(ABC, 3)
>>> a 
['q', 'h', 'x']
>>>''.join(a)
'qhx'
```

Edit: You can even choose the number in between 3 and 7 by using [randint](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/random.html#random.randint) of random module

```
>>> a = random.sample(ABC, random.randint(3,7))
>>> ''.join(a)
'bvt'
>>> b = random.sample(ABC, random.randint(3,7))
>>> ''.join(b)
'fycu'
```

Comment: Yep, I know that ;) However:

We have 44 letters in the Hungarian alphabet (as a result, there are 44 letters (elements) in the list ABC [or whatever we call it, it doesn't matter right now]), and I would like to have a random word from them containing 3-7 letters. I know how to generate a random word with 3 letters, a random word with 4 letters, a random word with 5 letters, etc. separately(!). My problem is, that I can't define this 3-7 range at the same time.

Comment: @ÁdámTóth do you want `3,4,5,7` in order? or any number in between `3 and 7`

Comment: Any number between 3 and 7 but AjaiVeer Singh gave me a solution which I find perfect so I think my question has been answered. :) Thank you for your effort by the way!

Comment: Yes, it's the same solution. Glad it has been answered

Answer (score 0):

understood your question now :

```
import random
ABC = ['A', 'Á', 'B', 'C'...]
letter_random = random.randint(3,7)
word = random.sample(ABC, letter_random)
print(''.join(word))
```

Comment: Aren't string, integer, list, etc. all variables?

Anyways, I know how to select elements from a given list. We have 44 letters in the Hungarian alphabet (as a result, there are 44 letters (elements) in the list ABC [or whatever we call it, it doesn't matter right now]), and I would like to have a random word from them containing 3-7 letters. I know how to generate a random word with 3 letters, a random word with 4 letters, a random word with 5 letters, etc. separately(!). My problem is, that I can't define this 3-7 range at the same time.

Comment: you want to get the word of range 3 to 7 letters ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! That is my real problem since python gives ValueError if I write the code like this (for example):

name = random.sample(ABC, 3, 7) or name = random.sample(ABC, 3-7)

Comment: @AdamToth, now check the solution... you will find it working perfectly. :)

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!!! :) And I am really sorry if I couldn't explain my question properly... English isn't my mother tongue - and I've just started coding as well... :D Thank you again! :)

Comment: glad you found your solution... though now you found two of them... :D